# Unexpected (IMO) constant-conversion warning

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, constexpr

consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

static constexpr uint8_t a = 0x80;
static constexpr uint8_t b = ~a;
```

It produces the following warning:

```
<source>:5:30: warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'const uint8_t' (aka 'const unsigned char') changes value from -129 to 127 [-Wconstant-conversion]

static constexpr uint8_t b = ~a;
```

I do not understand, why overflow warning is here, there is no explicite int in this code. I am operating on variables with the same type.
When removing constexpr, warning disappears, when changing to:

```
static constexpr uint8_t b = uint8_t{~a};
```

warning disappears. So looks like `~` operator implicitly changes variable to `int`?

Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: What is `a`? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question would have been useless once the link rotted, so I moved the content into the question.

Comment: Please read about [*usual arithmetic conversions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: yes but an iteresting point is that when the variables are `const` or `constexpr` qualified the warning is raised (even if declared `extern`) but not when they are not const qualified...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `operator~` that accept integers shorter than `int`. In `~uint8_t(0x80)` `uint8_t` is first promoted to `int`, and returns an `int` result, hence the warning.

See [bitwise logic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic):

> First, operators `&`, `^`, and `|` perform usual arithmetic conversions on both operands and **the operator `~` performs integer promotions on its only operand**.
>
> **Integer promotions**
>
> Integer promotion is the implicit conversion of a value of any integer type with rank less or equal to rank of `int` or of a bit field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, to the value of type `int` or `unsigned int`
>
> If `int` can represent the entire range of values of the original type (or the range of values of the original bit field), the value is converted to type `int`. Otherwise the value is converted to `unsigned int`.